# Recover matrix X using pointers from rows in X to rows in matrix Y without doing loops in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, suppose I know how each rows of my N-row matrix `X` corresponds to rows in matrix `Y`. Specifically, suppose `X` is 1000-by-3, `Y` is 40-by-3, `v` is 1000-by-1, and `X(i,:) = Y(v(i,1),:)` for rows of `X`. Is there any efficient way to recover `X` using `Y` and `v` without making a loop over 1:1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index can be a vector:

```
X = Y(v,:);
```